# Simple digital circuit schematic question

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, logic-gates

Below you'll find the schematic for a circuit I have to build and analyze tomorrow for a lab.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOFPG5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Note that the blocks I've shown labeled "+5V" are not accurately drawn; the symbol my instructor uses is a triangle, but I couldn't seem to find it in the editor.)

Firstly, will I require three separate +5V supplies to build the circuit I've shown? In the lab we use a rack-mount power supply, so my guess is that one would be acceptable since a voltage source (ideally) should output the same voltage regardless of the circuit it's hooked up to. Is this logic correct? Not seeing a physically connecting loop in a schematic always throws me off.

Secondly, are the grounds going to the same place? How does one tell? Towards the end of last semester in the lab we built some circuits with floating (also called virtual I believe) ground, and I never got a full understanding of the idea itself.

Comment: Virtual ground means the point in the circuit has the same potential as ground (so voltage diff is zero) but this point is not connected to ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to both of your questions. The symbols used for "+5V" or "Vcc" or "ground" are simply notational conveniences which mean "all the stuff with this symbol is connected together". We can also assume, if it isn't explicitly drawn, that there is a 5V power supply connected across "+5V" and "ground".

It doesn't mean anything beyond that. It's a common beginner mistake to think that "ground" means something special. It doesn't.

An exactly equivalent schematic can be drawn without those symbols:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw3wsa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

...but since power supply connections are so common, that would mean some very long lines to follow over the schematic. Not a big deal for a simple schematic as you have, but for something non-trivial with a schematic spanning many pages, you can imagine...

Comment: Hey thanks! Very informative! So it's kind of like a shorthand?

Comment: @Lefty It's exactly a shorthand. That's why you can't find any "grounds" or "Vccs" in the parts drawer.

Comment: @Lefty R1 and R2 are not needed for this to work as intended. If either switch closes it will ground a diode and shut the LED down.

Comment: @andy aka, thanks for the heads up. We've just begun introducing diodes and transistors, so I haven't gotten around to analyzing the circuit yet. Why does grounding a diode shut the LED down? Does it have to do with forward/reverse bias?

Comment: It certainly does.